# changing locations in django satchmo

Tags: django, satchmo

I am using Satchmo(skeleton project that comes in the projects folder when you download Satchmo) but am not in the US. I see that by default there is a Zipcode/Postcode* and list of states on the checkout page.

My question is, is the best way to change this(location details, billing information) to edit the /satchmo/apps/satchmo_store/shop/models.py file (hard edit the Order model)
or is there a better way to maybe set your location to a place other than the USA?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm not sure what implication a change like this might have throughout the skeleton project if I just deleted the zip code column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. go to /admin/l10n/country/ and mark the appropriate countries as active
2. go to /admin/shop/config/, select the site (probably localhost) and set the default shipping country and possible shipping countries
3. if you want to control whether the state and ZIP are requred or not, go to /settings/ , select "Satchmo Shop Settings" and modify "Required billing data", "Required shipping data" and "State required?" settings.